# Como mover un objeto clickado al centro de un plano Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity

basicamente tengo un **mapa** hecho con **planos** (20x10 casillas) y lo que quiero conseguir es que si yo pulso en una casilla despues de pulsar un personaje, este se mueva al centro de la casilla independientemente de donde haga click.
Lo unico que he conseguido es una mecanica similar a la del **League of Legends**, que donde haces *click* se mueve tu personaje, pero quiero dividir el mapa en casillas como he explicado al principio. por mas que busco no encuentro nada, y me seria de gran ayuda si me pudierais dar una solucion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero que tienes que hacer es detectar en que casilla estas haciendo click. Esto lo puedes hacer con raycast por ejemplo. Una vez detectes a donde quieres ir, luego tendras que mover el transform al punto seleccionado. Si puedes moverlo directamente bastaria con algo asi:

```
public GameObject myPersonaje;
public GameObject casilla1;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) {
           if (hit.collider.gameobject.name == "casilla1") {
             myPersonaje.transform.position = casilla1.transform.position;
           }
        }  
    }
 }
```

Básicamente lo que hace este trozo de código es:
Cuando haces click en el botón izquierdo del ratón, lanza un raycast y mira con que estas chocando. Si el rayo choca con alguien y ese alguien tiene como nombre casilla1 entonces teleporta al jugador a la casilla.

Este código es algo rápido pero supongo que te valdrá para hacerte una idea.

PD: Para que el raycast choque con otros objetos se necesitan colliders.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, lo probaré a ver que tal me sale

Comment: No me vale esto, la idea es que yo pulse en una casilla y se mueva el personaje al centro de esa casilla, esto es algo asi como el lol pero yo quiero dividirlo en casillas

Comment: Teoricamente, lo que hace es que si pulsas en una casilla mueve al personaje al centro de la casilla. Que parte no te vale?

Comment: ya lo probé y  funciona, al verlo pensé que era algo parecido a algo que ya tenía que era al pulsar un punto en el plano el personaje se movia a ese punto. muchas gracias XD

Comment: @CarlosGuijarro Aquí te mueve al centro de la casilla porque me baso en que la transform.position del gameObject de tu objeto casilla tiene el pivote en el centro, si no es el caso habría que calcular el centro de cada casilla previamente.